# Псевдоэлемент реализация ::before?

Tags: html, css

как реализовать такой псевдоэлемент для #success

```css
#success::before {
    content: "-";
    color: green;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

```html
 <div id="success">Success</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/vitalikdark/pen/abmVGYw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы размеры для блока работали нужно задать элементу `display: inline-block` или `display: block`:

```css
#success::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .5em;
  border: .25em solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="success">Success</div>
```

Comment: норм ну крч я в кодепен тоже так сделал  )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="success"> &nbsp;Success</div>
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#success::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    color: green;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(100 195 137);
}
```